# Load remote image (JSON object) to image view

Tags: android

I am trying to load 2 JSON objects (text and an image) into a textview and imageview. I got the text part to appear but it crashes with the image. I tried various answers to other questions but cannot get it to work.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
TextView textText;
ListView listList;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

private static String url = "http://54.165.116.31/api/resource";

private static final String TAG_TEXT = "text";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2); 
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Button refresh_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.refresh_button);
    refresh_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {  
      new JSONParse().execute();
  }
});
}
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
   private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity2.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
  }
  @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    return json;
   }

   @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
       try{
       new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.text2))
            .execute(url);
        textText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        String text = json.getString(TAG_TEXT);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();           
        map.put(TAG_TEXT, text);

        oslist.add(map);

        listList =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity2.this, oslist,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_TEXT }, new int[] {
                R.id.text});
        listList.setAdapter(adapter);     
   } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }       
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
  ImageView textText2;

  public DownloadImageTask(ImageView textText2) {
      this.textText2 = textText2;
  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String urldisplay = urls[0];
      Bitmap webImage = null;
      try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        webImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return webImage;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      textText2.setImageBitmap(result);
  }
}
```

}

LogCat:

```
10-01 21:11:47.453: I/am_on_paused_called(6307): [0,com.amiephipps.thejunglegym.MainActivity]
10-01 21:11:47.552: W/Resources(6307): Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon) that varies with configuration!!
10-01 21:11:47.583: I/am_on_resume_called(6307): [0,com.amiephipps.thejunglegym.MainActivity2]
10-01 21:11:47.665: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:51.005: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:51.082: I/art(6307): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1555(112KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1258% free, 1149KB/3MB, paused 2.122ms total 117.748ms
10-01 21:11:51.170: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:51.260: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:51.313: I/art(6307): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 809(34KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1256% free, 1199KB/3MB, paused 29.547ms total 78.392ms
10-01 21:11:51.399: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:51.560: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:51.667: I/art(6307): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1260(53KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 1256% free, 1203KB/3MB, paused 914us total 300.136ms
10-01 21:11:51.697: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:52.065: I/Choreographer(6307): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-01 21:11:52.327: D/skia(6307): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

The text and image are data from a JSON API (the link is in the code), it looks like this:

{"text":"example.","image":"example.jpg"}

Thanks.

Comment: can't get what to work? does it crash? does it not load? "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything

Comment: The text displays and immediately after it freezes.

Comment: Can you post your LogCat showing what went wrong?

Comment: could you check what's the URL you passed to this function? new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.text2))
            .execute(url);

Comment: I made some changes.